# Abstract URL and Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes

I have the following URL and I would like to hide the query string as follow:

from this:

```
/main?a=3&date_in=20/03/2013&date_out=20/03/2013
```

to this:

```
/main?cars/from/2013/01/27/to/2013/02/26
```

where 3 means cars for example

```
date_in = from and then the date always on that format

and date_out = to and then the date always on that format.
```

I have created the following on global.asax:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("main", "main/{*queryvalues}", "~/default.aspx");
```

Any ideas on how could I do that?

Comment: Good formatting is always your friend..

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip, I will do it better next time :)

Comment: Anyone knows the answer for this?

Comment: 6 days and still no answer :(, does anyone read the questions?

Comment: You'll likely have to remove the ? because your not using the query string properly, but you could try using the parameters as a custom URL http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd329551.ASPX

Answer (score 0):

You may use this following code at your Application_Start of Global.asax

```
routes.MapPageRoute("date_range",
    "{main}/{a}/from/{fyear}/{fmonth}/{fday}/to/{tyear}/{tmonth}/{tday}",
    "~/Default.aspx");
```

and putting the next code at your Page_Load event of default.aspx you can retrieve data of "a", "date_in" and "date_out" as you likely want

```
string _strQuery = string.Format("you are using this {6} from: {2}/{1}/{0} to: {5}/{4}/{3}",
                Page.RouteData.Values["fyear"] as string,
                Page.RouteData.Values["fmonth"] as string,
                Page.RouteData.Values["fday"] as string,
                Page.RouteData.Values["tyear"] as string,
                Page.RouteData.Values["tmonth"] as string,
                Page.RouteData.Values["tday"] as string,
                Page.RouteData.Values["a"] as string);

Response.Write(_strQuery);
```